# Sending multiple values in header() function with GET method

Tags: php, header, get

my question is about the `header()` function. I'm trying to send 2 variables trough this function like this:

`header("Location:index.php?variable_1='true'&amp;variable_2='false'");`

I think its the problem in escaping `&amp;` but i tried it just with `&. Also, first variable gets initialized and I can acquire it by calling`$_GET['variable_1']` but the second one is none existent and is not initialized.

So my question is, can I send more than one value trough header() function via GET method?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: oh, I apologize. Hello, everyone!

Comment: You don't need to do `foo='bar'&bar='baz'`. Lose the quotes, so `foo=bar&bar=baz`. They're not needed and will only cause unnecessary complications.

Comment: if accepted as your answer please mark answer by clicking on tick button below any answer which is your answer

Answer (score 5):

yes,you can just in case to do that

```
header("Location: index.php?variable_1=true&variable_2=false");
```

you dont need to use '' this

Comment: im sorry. i was misunderstood. i can only pass one variable with this call header("Location:index.php?value1=false&value2=true"); The value1 variable is initialized but value2 is not. I cant access it with &amp; or with & but the first one i can.

Comment: when you redirected to new address is this the address when yo redirected?please look in address bar

index.php?variable_1=true&variable_2=false

Comment: now it works. before i posted a question, i tested it the same way and it didn't work. the same code now works. i apologize for wasting everyones time, im an idiot.

Comment: great that it works.please accept one answer and press on tick below of answer to accept as your answer and get 2 point

Comment: im affraid i dont have enough reputation to do that. i will remember to do that when my reputation rises.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header("Location:index.php?variable_1=true&variable_2=false");
```